# How to submit self-competed 8949 form with TaxAct?

Tags: united-states, taxes, cryptocurrency, software

my wife and I are using TaxAct to file our US tax return for 2021. I have a handful of crypto transactions that I made last year - there are about 8 transcactions and the total volume is ~$600. I have completed form 8949 myself, listing the transactions. However, when we are trying to submit the form through TaxAct, it is asking us to state which brokerage prepared the 8949 form. I completed the form myself, so didn't use a 'brokerage' and it seems we can't leave that field blank.

Can anyone advise on what is the correct procedure to submit a form 8949 for crypto transactions with TaxAct? I assume we should be able to submit a self-completed 8949 form (the wording of the IRS instructions seems to imply that we can)?

Comment: What field can you not leave empty? There's no "brokerage" field on form 8949.

Comment: @littleadv that's correct - there is no 'brokerage' field on form 8949. However, when we try to upload the 8949 form in TaxAct, the TaxAct software is asking for a 'brokerage' field to be filled out, and won't allow us to proceed if we leave it blank.

Comment: Follow the steps here: https://www.taxact.com/support/22389/2017/forms-8949-and-1099-b-entering-stock-transactions-in-program. At what step have you encountered the problem?